# How do I maintain modularity while using websockets in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am starting a project which will simulate a board game. I am planning to use websockets for a number of functions within the application, including, sending and receiving moves, receiving and publishing challenges, and sending and receiving in game messages. I am struggling with how to structure the code to maintain modularity.

```js
wsServer.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // all socket based functions go here
});
```

Things I have thought of doing:

1. Write all functions in other files then importing them and calling them from within the connection. I still think this is not great because it will just be a list of function calls.
2. On connection, store the socket maybe in an array and assign event listeners in various other files
3. Give access to the socket to other files someway so that I can define the event listeners then. Not sure how I would do this.

Direct answers would be great, I have also been trying to find mid level websocket apps. The only examples I can find are overly simple chat apps that fit in 100 lines.

Comment: FYI, `exports.socket = socket;` will not work.  This is something that happens at run-time (after exports are already loaded) and it's something that happens over and over again as each client connects.  Whatever you're trying to use this for, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: You can export a function/api that allows anyone else to add a listener to an incoming socket.  You store those listeners and then, when any new socket connects, you go through the store list and add the appropriate listeners.  Or, you can export a function that allows anyone else to register for `connection` events so they can set up their own listeners on any new socket.  Or, you just export the `wsServer` object and let anyone else set up their own `wsServer.on()` listeners.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, I removed `exports.socket = socket`. Exporting a function that allows anyone to register an event handler is a great Idea. I could even create a function which would set up event listeners on specific types of connections.

Comment: @jfriend00 exporting the wsServer is also a great idea and in hindsight probably extremely obvious. You have been an insane amount of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. Export the `wsServer` object so anyone importing your module can get access to it to install their own listeners on it such as their own `connection` listener.
2. Export a function/API that other modules can call to say what listeners they want on any incoming socket.  You would have to store those listeners and then when you got a new incoming connection, you would install the stored listeners on that socket.
3. Export a function/API that gets the current `wsServer` object so anyone can install their own listeners on it such as their own `connection` listener.  This is conceptually similar to option #1, but allows for the timing of the `wsServer` object to be more dynamic and may work better with the more static ESM exports.